# DIV equal height within floated "row"

Tags: jquery, css, height

Ok, so I have this code:

```
<div class='layout' style='width: 500px;'>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 300px;'></div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 200px;'></div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 100px;'></div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 300px;'></div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 100px;'></div>
</div>
```

Ok, so each DIV above is floated left, so what I get is two "rows" of DIV, the above row containing the first two, the second the three latter DIVs, right?

Ok, so each "layout_frame" can contain any content, so they will be of differing height, but I want the height to be equal WITHIN THE ROW. So the first two should perhaps both be 800px high, and the third latter should be, for example, 200px - based on the tallest DIV in the "row".

So I'm using jQuery position() to find out which ones that are in the same row, with this code:

```
var rows = new Array();
$("div.layout_frame").each(function(){
    var pos = $(this).offset().top;
    var height = $(this).height();
    if (height > rows[pos]){
        rows.pos = height;
    }
});
```

But that's as far as I've come. I'm setting "pos" to, say "124" which should be equal for the first two and not for the last three. But each "group" of DIVS should have the same height, based on the tallest.

I really hope I explained this correctly. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi, When I use your code, I get 3 rows : the first with div1, the second with div2 and div3, the third with div4 and div5 (divx with x as the order number)...
Could you please post your css?

Comment: WHy are you so determined to have all of the inner divs in a single outer div? Is there a specific reason why you need to do this?
By splitting each 'row' into an outer div of its own, surely things will be easier to control?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this (replace your jQuery with the following):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentTallest = 0;
    var currentRowStart = 0;
    var rowDivs = new Array();

    $('div.layout_frame').each(function(index) {

        if(currentRowStart != $(this).position().top) {

            // we just came to a new row.  Set all the heights on the completed row
            for(currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);

            // set the variables for the new row
            rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
            currentRowStart = $(this).position().top;
            currentTallest = $(this).height();
            rowDivs.push($(this));

        } else {

            // another div on the current row.  Add it to the list and check if it's taller
            rowDivs.push($(this));
            currentTallest = (currentTallest < $(this).height()) ? ($(this).height()) : (currentTallest);

        }
        // do the last row
        for(currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);

    });

});
```

Comment: If you'd also like to make the columns resize as you resize the window (and force elements to re-flow), you can check out my blog post on extending this solution:  http://stephenakins.blogspot.com/2011/01/uniform-div-heights-for-liquid-css-p.html

Comment: @Ivanhoe123: Yep.  I wrote that solution and posted it here also, slightly modified to specifically to replace Sandman's code without any further modifications.

Answer (score 2):

you'd be better off laying it out like this:

```
<div class='layout' style='width: 500px;'>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 300px;'></div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 200px;'></div>
</div>
<div class='layout' style='width: 500px;'>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 100px;'></div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 300px;'></div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 100px;'></div>
</div>
```

then looking at whichever child div of each layout has the largest height, and set all of them to that height.

Comment: No, I will not be doing it this way. I want to solve it from the explanation in my OP, but thanks anyway

Comment: I think you need to answer the OP, as you don't know the exact problem he is solving.  also his problem is my problem and your solution does not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I have this code corresponding to your needs: I will update the code according to your wishes.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>frame layout</title>
<style  type="text/css"> 
div
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
}
.layout
{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='layout' style='width: 500px;'>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 300px;'>div1</div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 200px;'>div2</div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 100px;'>div3</div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 300px;'>div4</div>
  <div class='layout_frame' style='width: 100px;'>div5</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That breakes up the DIV in two parents, and as such is not something I can use. These are all in the same DIV

Comment: Ok, I changed it...
May be you can add another class (class='layout_frame div1_height' and class='layout_frame div2_height') to change in the same way the two sets of div (using javascript to change css values)?

Comment: Well, the width is dynamic, so maybe one of the DIVS will grow and shrink so that DIV3 all of a sudden fits in row 1, this is all dynamic, so I need to update the heights as it changes.

Comment: ok. What you have to know is that IE or firefox (maybe others) do not calculate border and margin in the same way: one includes border in the width calculation, the other count it apart...
Maybe you can find something already done here : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C13/